# Does cointegration test of exogenous variable with Y variable make sense when doing ARIMAX/SARIMAX?

Tags: time-series, quantitative, cointegration, arima

The cointegration test between two time series variable is generally relevant from my understanding when you are performing a regression model. In terms of ARIMA model the approach is straightforward to use the **Box-Jenkins methodology** to build the ARIMA model.

> https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-forecasting-performance-of-models.html

But when using an ARIMAX model (consisting of **multiple time series macro-economic variables**), do we need to specifically do the cointegration test of exogenous variable against our dependent variable. Since to what I understand these exogenous variables are added to ARIMA as external multiple regression (x) variables. Also, any further assumptions/tests to be performed or assessed before adding these exogenous factors to the modelling of ARIMAX.

> FYI: I am using the stats package from python to model this arimax.

Comment: Given that your question is not about finance and that some forecasting experts cluster in Cross Validated Stack Exchange, I think that site would be a better fit for your question.

Comment: Thank you! I will post the question there. I will delete this post if I don't receive any updates on this soon anytime soon